# how do I add 90 days to a calculated column?

Tags: calculated-column

I have 3 columns, for simplicity we'll say column A, column B and Calc Column. In the Calc Column I need a formula for the following:

```
If column A is blank, and column B is greater than 90 days from today then "No".
If column A is blank, and column B is greater than 83 days from today then "Upcoming".
If column A is blank, and column B is less than or equal to 83 days from today then "Yes".
If Column A is less than or equal to 90 days from column B then "Yes". 
Otherwise "no".
```

I had the following, but it's not working:

```
=IF(AND([TPM/TPC Complete]="",TODAY()-[RA Date]>90),"NO"=IF(AND([TPM/TPC Complete]="",TODAY()-[RA Date]>83),"UPCOMING"=IF(AND([TPM/TPC Complete]="",TODAY()-[RA Date]<=83),"YES"=IF([TPM/TPC Complete]-[RA Date]<=90,"Y","N"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of days between two dates in a calculated column we use this:

`DATEDIF([Today], [Column1],"d")`

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) a reference on calculated column formulas.

BUT, using `[Today]` is pointless in a SharePoint calculated column because the value of it will only change when the item is changed.

See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d12bf326-1a17-45b0-9f35-dc510bd798e6/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-for-example-duedate-vs-today?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) loads of resources on how you can get around this issue.

Note: you seem to have a syntax error in your formula anyway. There should only be one `=` and that should be at the beginning of the formula. You would need to replace the other `=`'s with a comma `,`